# Prolog count the number of times a predicate is true

Tags: prolog, aggregate-functions

I want to count the number of times a custom predicate is true.
For example, I have the following code:

```
is_man(john).
is_man(alex).
?:-is_man(X).
```

`X` will return `john`, then if I press semicolon it will also return `alex`, then `false`.

I want to build something like:

```
count(is_man(X), Count).
```

And this to return

```
Count = 2
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930340/aggregate-3-in-swi-prolog/5930420

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In SWI-Prolog:

```
aggregate_all(count, is_man(X), Count).
```

Comment: Is it possible to create a distinct count?
like, if you have 2 times the same name,not to increase the counter

Comment: @Shevliaskovic: The short answer is yes, it is possible.  `aggregate_all/3` above uses `findall/3` and counts solutions found by backtracking, including identical solutions.  However `aggregate_all/4` and `aggregate/4` allow counting [in a way that disregards duplicates](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate).  This might be worth a separate Question by you.

Answer (score 13):

For an ISO standard Prolog solution, you might use **findall/3** to produce a list of all solutions, then set Count to the length of the resulting list.  It could be a bit tricky to wrap this into a user-defined predicate **count/2** as you propose, because we need to form the first argument of **findall/3** in a way that accounts for any free (unbound) variables in the goal you want to pass as the first argument of **count/2**.

Many Prologs provide for "counters" or other forms of mutable global values, a nonstandard extension, that could be used in connection with a failure driven "loop" to make the same count.  Slightly more cumbersome but sticking to the letter of the Prolog standard would be to use **assert** and **retract** to create your own "counter" by adjusting a dynamic fact.

An illustration of the latter approach follows.  Making it "multithread safe" would require additional logic.

```
count(Goal,_) :-
    setGoalCount(0),
    call(Goal),
    incGoalCount(1),
    fail.              /* or false in some Prologs */
count(_,Count) :-
    getGoalCount(Count).

setGoalCount(_) :-
    retract(getGoalCount(_)),
    fail.
setGoalCount(X) :-
    assert(getGoalCount(X)).

incGoalCount(Y) :-
    retract(getGoalCount(X)),
    !,
    Z is X + Y,
    assert(getGoalCount(Z)).
```

Comment: It's not about being "multithread safe". Simple nesting does not work `count(count((true;true),_),C).` should give 1, but you get 3. Also, ISO does not have `assert/1` but `asserta/1` and `assertz/1`.

Comment: Hi, yeah, reminds me of comp.lang.prolog thread we recently had! Would be also a business case for sys_make_surrogate/1 and setup_call_cleanup/3, if no findall/3 or "global variables" solution is desired.

Answer (score 10):

```
count(P,Count) :-
        findall(1,P,L),
        length(L,Count).
```

Comment: I can't find the library that contains the function `length()` or `findall()`

Comment: @Tarek Both are built-in predicates and do not belong to any special library. You can use them directly, without any library import.