# Prolog fact and query

Tags: prolog

I have facts :

```
studies(it, da).      // IT branch studies the module DA
studies(it, pm).
studies(ie, pm).
studies(it, plc).
studies(it, se).
studies(cs, plc).
studies(cs, da).
studies(cs, se).
```

I need to write queries for:

1. How many subjects do cs students study?
2. Which branch studies the subjects pm and plc?

Comment: No..these are facts..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `aggregate_all(count, studies(cs, X), Count).` (See [Prolog count the number of times a predicate is true](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6060268/223267))
2. `studies(X, pm), studies(X, plc).`

Comment: Can you plz tell what is difference between a rule and a query.Actually i am a newbie to prolog.

Comment: @Hacker688 A rule has the form `<Head> :- <Body>`, where `Head` names a predicate which takes from 0-n arguments which are either variables or ground terms and `Body` lays out a set of conditions which must be met if `Head` is to be true. We can read rule thus: 'Head is true if every statement in Body is true'. A fact is essentially a rule of the form `<Head> :- true`. A query is entered at the top level, after the prompt `?-` and asks if a certain statement is true. Prolog tries to prove that the queried statement is true by testing whether it follows from the existing facts and rules.