# Find how many same objects exist

Tags: prolog

I have this code

```
color(blue).
color(red).
color(blue).
color(green).
```

I want to make a rule that will count how many times the X color exists.
For this case count_color(X) should return 2.

Is that possible in this way or i have to make a list with the colors?

Comment: Do you mean that after calling `count_color(blue, X)`, `X` should be 2?

Comment: This question covers the same ground as [this earlier one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060268/prolog-count-the-number-of-times-a-predicate-is-true), which presents a method of solution not yet described here (assert/retract) besides the two which are.

Answer (score 2):

`aggregate/3` does not exist in ISO prolog, so it's not available in all implementations. But you can get the same result using `findall/3`, as in:

```
count_color(Color, N) :- findall(_, color(Color), List), length(List, N).
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible by using the `aggregate/3` predicate:

```
count_color(Color, N) :- aggregate(count, color(Color), N).
```

A pointer for using `aggregate/3`: [aggregate/3 in swi-prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930340/aggregate-3-in-swi-prolog)